# Installing Anchor-CMS without Composer

Tags: composer-php, anchor-cms

I need to install anchor-cms-0.12.1 without using composer in my Ubuntu system.

It's showing:

> "We were unable to run composer our selves. Please run "composer
>   install" from the command line to install Anchor. If you do not have
>   composer installed please see getcomposer.org/";

I downloaded from https://github.com/anchorcms/anchor-cms and followed the steps as described but was unable to find Composer.

If I try  to install composer it does not allow me to create `composer.phar`, it shows unable to open `composer.phar`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? What error messages are shown? If you want to get answers and help, you've to provide more informations.

Comment: ya i had tried Its showing      "We were unable to run composer our selves. Please run "composer install" from the command line to install Anchor. If you do not have composer installed please see https://getcomposer.org/"

Comment: add the informnations you have to the question. It's far more readable. Look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)